# Estou criando um sistema escolar, quero juntos uma lista de professores vinculados e materias Banco (MySql)

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou criando um sistema escolar, quero juntor uma lista de professores vinculados a materias e virse e versa. Utilizo o banco Mysql

Exemplo:

```
Professor 1 - Materia 1
Professor 1 - Materia 2
Professor 1 - Materia 3
Professor 2 - Materia 1
Professor 2 - Materia 3
```

Onde o mesmo professor pode ser relacionado em mais de uma matéria, e a mesma matéria pode ser relacionado em mais de um professor!
Tem alguma forma de realizar este procedimento

Comment: Qual seria a estrutura do banco e como vc quer esse retorno?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você precisa é de um relacionamento n x n, ou seja, muitos para muitos. Este tipo de relacionamento entre duas tabelas exige uma terceira tabela que conterá as chaves estrangeiras das duas tabelas em questão. Ex:

[image: Exemplo de relacionamento NxN]